# How to Leverage browser caching at ASP.net IIS 7.5

Tags: caching, browser, iis-7, browser-cache, lifetime

The following cacheable resources have a short freshness lifetime. Specify an expiry of at least one week in the future for the following resources:

http://pagespeed.googlelabs.com suggest me this for my website as a high priority. I am using windows server 2008 r2 netframework 4.0 asp.net IIS 7.5 . How do i do this ?

This is the direct url for you to see  : http://pagespeed.googlelabs.com/#url=www.monstermmorpg.com&mobile=false&rule=LeverageBrowserCaching

Comment: I found this and applied but pagespeed.googlelabs still showing the problem : http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/staticContent/clientCache

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You might start here with [this article](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/710/configure-iis-7-output-caching/), also Mads Kristensen had written an [interesting](http://madskristensen.net/post/performance-tuning-tricks-for-aspnet-and-iis-7-part-1) [blog post](http://madskristensen.net/post/performance-tuning-tricks-for-aspnet-and-iis-7-e28093-part-2) on how to compress, minify and cache dynamic and static content on your website.

```
<configuration> 
 <location path="showStockPrice.asp">     
   <system.webserver>        
     <caching>         
       <profiles>
         <add varybyquerystring="*"location="Any"
           duration="00:00:01" policy="CacheForTimePeriod"            
           extension=".asp">
       </profiles>
     </caching>
   </system.webserver>
 </location>
```

To cache static content

```
<staticContent>
 <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00"/>
</staticContent>
```

Comment: this is about PHP. i am trying to cache images css js static content

Comment: Ok i did what you suggested. I also find it from here too http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/staticContent/clientCache  but pagespeed google still telling me that i am not leverage browser caching

Comment: can you post the exact error message and possibly what files it is complaining about. If you have some third party plugins from twitter, facebook, google analytics etc then there isn't much you could improve further.

Comment: Adding the <staticContent> element to my web.config file did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: The `interesting` and `blog post` links are broken.