# Leverage Browser caching for static resources (only specific files) in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Setting an expiry date or a maximum age for static resources programatically only for specific files (.css,.js,.png)

Any other way instead of altering web.config

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Leverage browser caching at ASP.net IIS 7.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634302/how-to-leverage-browser-caching-at-asp-net-iis-7-5)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634302/how-to-leverage-browser-caching-at-asp-net-iis-7-5?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074198/leverage-browser-caching-in-iis-google-pagespeed-issue?rq=1